# ImageButton validation group not working

Tags: asp.net

I have a Gridview and inside gridview I have a Footer Template..the Footer template contains
a TextBox with two validation controls i.e RequiredField and RangeValidator and there is a ImageButton to "Add" row. When user presses the Image Button it is trapping error but once provide value within range and press "Add" nothing happens i mean submission doesn't occur. When I remove rangevalidator then it works as expected. I guess the problem is that one plugin called "autonumeric" is binded with the field which accepts only in numeric format and textbox is string format and rangevalidator type is integer..is it something causing the problem? how do i fix it.

**Here is the code of FooterTemplate**

```
<FooterTemplate>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnAdd" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" CausesValidation="true" ImageUrl="/Style%20Library/Images/add.png" ToolTip="New Record" ValidationGroup="GridViewFooterRowGroup"/>
</FooterTemplate>
```

**Here is the code for Item Template**

```
<asp:TemplateField>
 <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtftrQty" runat="server" Text="0" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvQty" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtftrQty" Text="*" Display="Dynamic" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="GridViewFooterRowGroup" > </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RvFtrQty" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Type="Integer" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="999999" ControlToValidate="txtftrQty" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="GridViewFooterRowGroup" ></asp:RangeValidator>
  </FooterTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Why do you need the RangeValidator for?

Comment: Quantity cannot be zero and it has a range between 1 - 99999

Comment: Why are you putting the code in the template field in the footer?
also try to put them all together?
let me know if that work

Comment: If you put 0 do you see the `*` error message? How bout when you put a valid value? Does the error message disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Subjet: GridView with Shopping Cart Basket logic

Hi,

Try the following code. I have attached different ValidationGroup to each control inside GridView's RowDataBound event.

ASPX Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <h2>GridView with Shopping Cart Basket logic</h2>

    <asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        onrowdatabound="gvProducts_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SN">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSN" runat="server" Text='<%# (Container.DataItemIndex + 1) %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductPrice" DataFormatString="{0:C2}" 
                HeaderText="Product Price" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Quantity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxProductQuantity" runat="server" MaxLength="10">
                    </asp:TextBox> 
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtbxProductQuantity" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Product Quantity"
                         ControlToValidate="tbxProductQuantity" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" 
                         Text="*">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvtbxProductQuantity" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only numbers (integer) are allowed in 'Product Quantity' field."
                         ControlToValidate="tbxProductQuantity" Display="Dynamic" Operator="DataTypeCheck" SetFocusOnError="true" 
                         Text="*" Type="Integer">
                    </asp:CompareValidator>
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add To Basket">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddToBasket" runat="server" Text="Add To Basket"/>
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulategvProducts();
        }
    }

    private void PopulategvProducts()
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            products.Add(new Product(i,"Product-" + i.ToString(),(i * 3)));  
        }

        gvProducts.DataSource = products;
        gvProducts.DataBind();  
    }

    protected void gvProducts_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox tbx = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("tbxProductQuantity");
            RequiredFieldValidator rfv = (RequiredFieldValidator)e.Row.FindControl("rfvtbxProductQuantity");
            CompareValidator cv = (CompareValidator)e.Row.FindControl("cvtbxProductQuantity");
            Button btn = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnAddToBasket");

            string validationGroupText = "AddProductToBasket" + (e.Row.DataItemIndex + 1).ToString();

            tbx.ValidationGroup = validationGroupText;
            rfv.ValidationGroup = validationGroupText;
            cv.ValidationGroup = validationGroupText;
            btn.ValidationGroup = validationGroupText; 
        }
    }
}

public class Product
{
    private int _ProductID;
    public int ProductID
    {
        get { return _ProductID; }
        set{_ProductID = value;}
    }

    private string _ProductName;
    public string ProductName
    {
        get { return _ProductName; }
        set { _ProductName = value; }
    }

    private double _ProductPrice;
    public double ProductPrice
    {
        get { return _ProductPrice; }
        set { _ProductPrice = value; }
    }

    public Product(int productID,string productName,double productPrice)
    {
        _ProductID = productID;
        _ProductName = productName;
        _ProductPrice = productPrice; 
    }
}
```

or

http://forums.asp.net/t/1275010.aspx/1